# how can i get all record for user on select type

Tags: php, html, ajax, select

I have an HTML text input field - for example:

```
<input id="CustID" name="CustID" dir="rtl" value="<? echo $CustID;?>" size="35" required="true" maxlength="9" >
```

When I insert the number of the user, I need to open a select box to show all ticket for this user.

for example

```
    <select name="ticket" id="ticket" >
<? 
$query="SELECT * FROM ticket where CustID='$CustID' ";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die("error: " . mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>  
    <option  value="<?php echo $row['ticket'] ; ?>"><?php echo $row['ticket'] ; ?></option>   
<? }  ?>
    </select>
```

How can i use this with AJAX?

This is what I have so far:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
function getData(id) {
        $.ajax ({
           url: "php_page.php",
           type: "POST",
           data: {custid:id},
           success: function(data){
                    $("#return").html(data)
                    }
        )} // i have error her why ??
}

</script>

   <input type="text" value="<?php echo $CustID;?>" onkeyup="getData(this.value)"/>
    <?   
    include("functions/connect.php");
    $query = "select * from customers2 ,  tickets where customers2.CustID='".$CustID."' and tickets.CustNo=customers2.CustomersNo";
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die("error: " . mysqli_error());
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    ?>  
      <option  value="<?php echo $row['ticket'] ; ?>"><?php echo $row['ticket'] ; ?></option>   
    <? }  ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: Just so you know you should stop using the old mysql functions and upgrade to either PDO or the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) library for security issues.

Comment: Close, now just move everything below your `<input/>` line into a separate file named "php_page.php"  Also, you have no opening tag for `<select>`  put that at the top of your "php_page.php" page

Comment: Also, it is recommended to always use `<?php` instead of the shorter `<?`, since the short tags are deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your php on a separate page called php_page.php.  Create your [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call using the jquery library on your display page:

```
function getData(id) {
        $.ajax ({
           url: "php_page.php",
           type: "POST",
           data: {custid:id},
           success: function(data){
                    $("#return").html(data)
                    }
        )}
}
```

On your form page create a div with id "return" where you want your select options to show up and also call this function either with a button click or onkeyup:

```
   <input type="text" value="<?php echo $CustID;?>" onkeyup="getData(this.value)"/>
```

Oh, and your mysql connect should use the [mysqli library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php):

```
    $con=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database);
    $query = //same as before
    $result=mysqli_query($query) or die("error: " . mysqli_error());
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
      ?>  
      <option  value="<?php echo $row['ticket'] ; ?>"><?php echo $row['ticket'] ; ?></option>   
    <? }  ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: I provided links to the jquery library ajax function as well as the mysqli library.  You'll have to do a little research here, can't do it all for you.  If you don't have it, download it [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) and place it at the top of your document in `<script src="your_path_to_jquery_file"></script>`

Comment: I added the comment on the original question.  You're close, now just move everything below your <input/> line into a separate file named "php_page.php" Also, you have no opening tag for <select> put that at the top of your "php_page.php" page

Answer (score 0):

use AJAX to pass CustID to Select page.

i.e

index.php

```
<script>
function callAjax(str)
{
 ajax
}
</script>
<input type = "text" name = "CustID" onblur="callAjax()"/>
<div id = "show">where to display the ajax results</div>
```

ajax.php

```
all that code with the select and options.
```

Comment: i was assuming the author knows how to use ajax. let me edit it.

Comment: sorry but i need when i insert number in input type , open on other div the select type have all record and i select which i need

Comment: that is actually how you do it, let me expand it more for you.

Comment: sorry but i need when i insert number in input type , open on other div the select type have all record and i select which i need

Comment: Ah, touche.  I see your point.  I tend to always assume that people asking are just completely lost (no offense khalid), because I know I've been there before.

Comment: sorry but i need when  i insert the number i need open div have select that have all record for this user how ?? i need full code

Answer (score 0):

i will do but the result is get me all record on select and i wont only record of the user i enter ID

index.php

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
function getData(id) {
        $.ajax ({
           url: "php_page.php",
           type: "GET",
           data: {custid:id},
           success: function(data){
                    $("#return").html(data)
                    }
        })
}


</script>
<input type="text" id="CustID" name="CustID" onkeyup="getData(this.value)"/>
<div id="return"></div>
```

php_page.php

```
<select>
<option  value="">عرض الكل</option>
<?   
include("functions/connect.php");
if(isset($_GET['CustID']))
{
$CustID = $_GET['CustID'];
$sql_check = mysql_query("select * from customers2 , omra , haj , tickets where customers2.CustID='".$CustID."' and tickets.CustNo=customers2.CustomersNo") or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($sql_check)){
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql_check)){

?>  
<option  value="<?php echo $rows['TicketType'] ; ?>">تذكرة <?php echo $rows['TicketType'] ; ?> برقم <?php echo $rows['TicketRealNo'] ; ?></option>   
<? } } ?>
</select>
<? } ?>
```